# Find the first word after a comma in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in SAS that I need to find each of these codes. Each letter represents a different food group. I did consider taking the first three characters and then the first three characters after each comma but the character length is variable and it includes reference to the type of orange juice then too which is not my intention.

Reprex:

```
Diet
p10 - pumpkin,h13 - lollipop
p18 - potato
h13 - lollipop, d80 - orange juice, without pulp
b423 - cinnamon,d80.5 - orange juice with pulp, strained,h40 - apple-cinnamon muffins
d93.8 - apple juice
h40 - apple-cinnamon muffins
```

My intended outcome:

```
Diet_1  Diet_2  Diet_3
p10     h13
p18
h13     d80
b423    d80.5   h40
d93.8
h40
```

Any suggestions or references to similar problems would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have a list of values delimited by commas. Each value has a code and a description delimited by hyphen.  Do any of the descriptions ever include a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Feel free to ask :-)

```
data have;
input diet $ 1-200;
infile datalines truncover;
datalines;
p10 - pumpkin,h13 - lollipop
p18 - potato
h13 - lollipop, d80 - orange juice, without pulp
b423 - cinnamon,d80.5 - orange juice with pulp, strained,h40 - apple-cinnamon muffins
d93.8 - apple juice
h40 - apple-cinnamon muffins
;

data want(keep = diet_:);
   set have;
   array diet_{3} $;
   j = 1;
   do i = 1 to countw(diet);
      w = scan(diet, i, ' ,');
      if prxmatch('/\w\d+\.*\d*/', w) then do;
         diet_[j] = w;
         j + 1;
      end;
   end;
run;
```

Result:

```
diet_1 diet_2 diet_3 
p10    h13   
p18     
h13    d80   
b423   d80.5  h40 
d93.8     
h40
```

Answer (score 3):

The list of values appear to be separated by commas.  So just use SCAN() to pick each value from the list. Then use SCAN() again to take the part before the hyphen.  So assuming your current dataset is named HAVE and the variable is named REPREX you could do this:

```
data want;
   set have;
   array diet_ [10] $7 ;
   do index=1 to min(dim(diet_),countw(REPREX,','));
     diet_[index]=scan(scan(REPREX,index,','),1,'-');
   end;
   drop index;
run;
```

You can adjust the number of variables to create and the length of each variable in the ARRAY statement.